# How can i extract my best move from Min Max in TicTacToe?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minmax

```
        int minmax(Board game, int depth)
        {
            if (game.IsFinished() || depth < 0)
                return game.Score(game.Turn);

            int alpha = int.MinValue + 1;
            foreach (Point move in game.Generate_Moves())
            {
                Board currentBoard = game;
                currentBoard.Do_Move(move); 

                alpha = max(alpha, -minmax(currentBoard, depth-1));
                currentBoard.Undo_Move(move);
            }

            return alpha;
        }
```

The thing is that this little function tells me if the game is a win, a lose or a draw, but how can i get the move that will led me to a win? My Point class is a simple Class With 2 coordinates X, Y and i want to get the answer as a point so i can latter say something like `game.Do_Move(myPoint)`.

In case some functions aren't obvious:

`game.IsFinished()` - returns true if win/lose/draw else otherwise

`game.Score(turn)` - returns -1/0/1 in case is a lose/draw/win for the player with the next move

`game.Generate_Moves()` - returns a List with available moves

`game.Do_Move()` - void that applies the move to game

`game.Undo_Move()` - talks for itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be enough if the minimax function which gets called on the root node of the game tree returns both, the choosen move and the score. For all other nodes of the game tree, the function needs only to return the score. Thus the usual way is to implement two slightly different minimax functions – [Look at Note #2 in the description to this NegaMax Framework](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Alpha-Beta#Implementation-Negamax%20Framework).
Applied to your minimax interface you would have following additional function:

```
int minimaxWithMove(Board game, int depth, Point& choosen)
{
    assert (!game.IsFinished() && depth > 0); // not possible at root node
    int alpha = int.MinValue + 1;
    foreach (Point move in game.Generate_Moves())
    {
        Board currentBoard = game;
        currentBoard.Do_Move(move);
        int score = -minmax(currentBoard, depth-1);
        if (score > alpha)
        {
            alpha = score;
            choosen = move;
        }
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

Note that I have removed the call to `Undo_Move` as it is not needed because you make a copy of `game` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the [minimax theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)

You basically have to make a game tree, where each node in the tree is a board position, and each child is the result of a legal move.  The leaf nodes (where the game is ended) will have scores according to game.score(), and one player is trying to pick moves down a path leading to a high score, while the other is trying to pick moves that force a low score.  The theorem will help you see how to apply that idea, rigorously.

Comment: The idea is that my program works and tells me if I (with both players) got a chance to win / to draw or the other player can win. After I make my first move with X it tells me its gonna end in a draw, but if I pick some random bad square for O it will tell me that its a win for X and so on. Therefore the algorithm works, being slow btw, but it works. It takes all the possible squares and and announce my best try but I want to get the the path which the algorithm takes to the winning state.

Comment: Right, so trace your way back up the tree from the winning leaf.